# Node - Fastest way to store an array outside of memory

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, database, file

**Problem:** I've got an app that's working with a large number of arrays, specifically, around 20k separate arrays of length 1000 items (integers, if it matters) each. I've recently moved away from objects to reduce the amount of raw data I'm serializing (and eventually parsing) and switched to arrays to make it easier to handle and serialize but now I'm not sure how to store the data.

**Question:** If I'm looking for the fastest way to load any random array back into memory (and subsequently off-loading them) should I be storing these arrays in some other format other than a database (CSV, file, json..), should I be putting each array in a table with just two columns, one for the increment id and one for the array's value (some integer of variable length), or some sort of database that allows/encourages arrays natively?

**My Thoughts:** I was originally going to just store each array in a table with two columns as described above, but this leads me to believe I would have two problems: 1) I wouldn't be able to "save" each array while it's in memory to the database without having to format it in any way (i.e I want functionality similar to "insert into table1 array1"). 2) I want to be able to read the whole array in one line just by selecting the table without any formatting (i.e "select table1" => [x, y, z..]). While I know MariaDB and other SQL databases have a useArray feature, I don't believe they work how I want them to.

**Goal:** I need some method of storing an array outside of my app's memory that can be called back up and read very quickly and ideally asynchronously. In an ideal world, I'd want speed comparable to a SQL DB or Redis store if I was using an object instead of an array.

I've thought about CSV files with some library or other file formats with FS, but how would these speeds compare to a database? My gut tells me they're likely too slow in comparison to even consider.

Thank you!

Edit: To clarify, I originally had "easiest" in the title. Easiness is not too important here, the speed I am able to get save the array and delete it from memory and subsequently load it back into memory is.

Edit 2: Random thought I just had since I'll be serializing this data once it's in-memory if I were to serialize it as a string, would it be easier to just store the string somehow then read each string and just split it with .split?

Comment: Do you want easiest or fastest?

Comment: @Strawberry lets go with fastest. Easiest is only important to me as I don't want to jump through a lot of hoops that will eventually make the solution not the fastest :)

Comment: Why can't you just store the array as a json object in mariadb (or mysql or mongo or whatever)

Comment: @mankowitz I looked into that but I felt as if going down that route would not give me any advantage over using objects (Am I wrong? I truly am unsure). I'm using arrays for other reasons now, but if I'm going to be using them I might as well try and squeeze all the performance I can out of the switch.

Comment: have you considered Redis? If you don't mind pushing this data to another service and use this service's memory, I believe Redis is what you are looking for.

Comment: @enapupe Redis' hash system makes it difficult to store arrays, but excellent for objects. If I used redis it would be no different than just converting into an object and saving it in any other db.

Comment: why you say it's difficult? i have used it to store snapshots in form of arrays, some service would push an entry to this array every 5minutes - and i'd retrieve that based on some key